# Calling ajax method from JavaScript using telerik

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, telerik

How can i use ASP.NET telerik ajax just to call server method from JavaScript's method and get some results, so transfer of parameters and result should be done using ajax, and after that i want to use JavaScript to update component? I need some example or things that i should use.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   //aspx
            <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest">

            </telerik:RadAjaxManager>





//client side


    function ToolbarButtonClick(sender, args){

     var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>");

     ajaxManager.ajaxRequest("test");


        return false;

    }







//server side


    Public Sub RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxRequestEventArgs)

        Select Case e.Argument

            Case "Send"

         ' something



        End Select

    End Sub
```

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/ajax/calling-server-side-method-from-javascript.aspx#742362